# Pow function calculation by dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I know that `pow(base, power)` is a built-in function in C with complexity O(power). Can I reduce the complexity of it by dynamic programming?

Comment: How do you know that? The standard doesn't say anything about the time-complexity for the [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function.

Comment: I had calculated normally. I'm not sure that complexity is O(n).

Comment: what is n? The length of input in bits?

Comment: afaik there's no dynamic programming way to improve pow. But you can get it to O(log n) by using divide and conquer, as some answers here have shown

Comment: n=power. It's a mistake mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate it in O(logn)

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    int temp;
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    temp = power(x, y/2);
    if (y%2 == 0)
        return temp*temp;
    else
        return x*temp*temp;
}
```

Details in [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/)

Answer (score 3):

If your input arguments are non-negative integers, then you can implement your own `pow`.

**Iteratively, with running time = O(n):**

```
unsigned long long pow(unsigned long long x,unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (n--)
        res *= x;
    return res;
}
```

**Recursively, with running time = O(n):**

```
unsigned long long pow(unsigned long long x,unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)
        return x;
    return pow(x,n/2)*pow(x,n-n/2);
}
```

**Efficiently, with running time = O(log(n)):**

```
unsigned long long pow(unsigned long long x,unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (n & 1)
            res *= x;
        n >>= 1;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is the complexity of those? Please specified that. May be it will be helpful @barak manos